# How to rule out the port on accessing localhost?

Tags: windows

I have deployed different servers (it can be any app server - tomcat, jboss, http etc.,) with different port in my localbox

```
ex:
   localhost:8080
   localhost:9090
   ..
   ..
```

Now i want to assign each link or url or the above to a name instead of typing the whole with port numbers so that i can share the same with other folks as well.

```
ex:
   mybridge.com
   mycompany.com
   myledger.com
   ..
```

How to do it? I'm using windows OS

Thanks

Comment: Do you already own these domain names? Have you already pointed them to your webserver? Do addresses like `mybridge.com:8080` or `mycompany.com:9090` already work at this time?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. What are you using to run the websites? IIS? Apache? Something else? Windows OS is not specific enough for us to know what you setup scenario is. Clarify that and we can give you a proper answer.

Comment: I'm using Apache Tomcat webserver. I don't want to access them with ports. I want to access with a domain name. In windows we would edit etc\host file. However it doesn't allow ports to be mentioned. So not sure how to do this in windows as well as in Mac OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an http URL doesn't have the port specified, it will *always* use port 80 (and https will use 443). You cannot change this through domain names. You need to have an actual program that listens on port 80 and proxies your requests to the correct web app – this is often called a "reverse proxy".

Apache httpd and Nginx can both be used as reverse proxies. For example, if you have Apache httpd, just configure a regular VirtualHost for each of your domains – all on the same port 80 – and specify ProxyPass instead of DocumentRoot. (Same in nginx.)